# How to add column named Zone to OleDb?

Tags: sql, oledb, oledbconnection, oledbcommand

I assume that "Zone" is a reserved keyword, so can I put it in quotes or something to make this work?  My DB connection is good.  I've added columns with different names.

```
String addZone = ALTER TABLE Streets ADD COLUMN Zone Text(50)
OleDbCommand com1 = new OleDbCommand(q1, mdbConnection);
com1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zone is a reserved keyword so you have to wrap it in brackets

```
String addZone = "ALTER TABLE Streets ADD COLUMN [Zone] Text(50)"
```

Answer (score 0):

See
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259228(SQL.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

For those who are looking for reasons and got here:

ZONE is a reserved ODBC keyword ([list of reserved keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)), so need to escape it, for example:

"Zone" - SQL standard

[Zone] - T-SQL

`Zone` - MySQL